# Need to copy dist folder to another folder after successful build Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering

Actually, I want to build my project on a server. The problem is that the build process deletes the dist folder before the build complete. If any error occurs while building a project, the website goes down. I want the dist folder will delete only after a successful build.
Or
Move the dist folder to another folder after a successful build.

Comment: ng build --prod --output-path=other/path

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am doing this to add SSR build folder(dist) to add inside of the build folder in React.js Redux.

**Step 1: webpack.build.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
}
```

**Step 2. webpack.server.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './server/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    filename: 'server.js'
  },
}
```

**Step 3. package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start && webpack-dev-server",
    "cleanBuild": "rimraf ./build/*",
    "build": "npm run cleanBuild && set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
    "server-build": "webpack --config webpack.build.config.js && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "serve:ssr": "node server.js"
  },
```

**Step 4: Make Build**

First, Build Normal
`npm run build`.
Second, build SSR
`npm run server-build`.
Third, run SSR Code & normal code by using `node server.js` and `npm run start`.